# FFmpeg massive data loss when writing large data and swapping segments

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I have an ffmpeg process running which continiously writes audio data to two 30 seconds (for testing, I'm actually planning to use 5 minutes) segments. The problem is that when I write some audio data with length more than size of two segments (60 seconds), ~8-17 seconds of audio is lost. Here is how I run FFmpeg and write data:

```
    _ffmpeg = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "ffmpeg",
        Arguments = 
            $"-y -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac {Channels} -i pipe:0 -c:a libmp3lame -f segment -segment_time {BufferDuration} -segment_format mp3 -segment_wrap 2 -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_list \"{_segmentListPath}\" \"{segmentName}\"",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true
    })!;
    // Channels is usually 1, BufferDuration is 30
```

And here is how I write data:

```
public async Task WriteSilenceAsync(int amount)
{
    if (amount > _size) amount = _size; // _size is 48000 * 1 * 2 * 30 * 2 = 5760000 (size of 1 minute of audio)
    
    var silence = _silenceBuffer.AsMemory(0, amount);
    await _ffmpeg.StandardInput.BaseStream.WriteAsync(silence);
}
```

I tried to change the ffmpeg parameters and ways I write data. But I haven't found the solution.

I'm sure that the problem is caused by ffmpeg segments, because if I disable segmenting and write audio to a single file, there are no problems with data loss or audio missmatch. I also sure that `amount` of silence to add in `WriteSilenceAsync()` method is calculated right. I'm not sure if the problem appears with data length more than 30 seconds but less then 1 minute, but I think it doesn't.

I don't know how to solve this problem and would be glad to see any suggestions or solutions.